# xsl:template & svg namespace disagreement between firefox & chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, xslt, svg, namespaces

I have a problem that seems to be related the svg names spaces. One way works with FireFox and the other way works with Chrome but neither way works with both. I have tried adding xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", but that doesn't change the results either way.

In the template below, the 'use' and 'text' tags are prefixed with 'svg':. This works in FireFox but not with Chrome. If I remove the 'svg:' prefix then it works in Chrome but not FireFox.

Is there a way that works with both?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template name="attribute-header">
 <svg:use xlink:href="#attribute-value-section-banner" x="{$location-x}" y="{$banner-y}"/>
 <svg:text class="attribute-label-text" x="{$center-line}" y="{$label-y}">
```

Comment: Please post enough code (XML+XSLT) to enable us to reproduce the problem. And explain what exactly "doesn't work" mean.

Comment: With XSLT and a result that is supposed to be a mix of (X)HTML and SVG you will need to decide what kind of result document you want, if you want it to be XML that uses namespaces with prefixes like you seem to want to do it, then you should use `<xsl:output method="xml"/>`. If you want to create HTML5 where you are allowed to use HTML and SVG elements then you need to make sure you use the SVG elements without prefix as HTML5 does not support prefixes and namespaces like you try with `svg:use`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote two test cases, one being http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015020801.xml that uses the stylesheet http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015020801.xsl with `xsl:output method="xml"`, the second being http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015020802.xml which uses the stylesheet http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015020802.xsl with `<xsl:output method="html"`. As long as the output method is `xml`, the XSLT can produce prefixed SVG elements (e.g. `svg:circle`) and all three browsers I have, IE 11, Firefox, and Chrome render the XHTML and the SVG just fine. In the second test case with output method `html` I have made sure that the SVG elements are not prefixed as neither HTML5 nor HTML 4 supports that syntax. Again all three browsers know how to render the HTML and SVG created that way by XSLT.

So I suppose you are mixing HTML output with XML namespaces and prefixed qualified names, decide whether you want to create XML with your XSLT, as in my first example, where you then have full support for XML and XML with namespaces syntax, or whether you want to create HTML5 with your XSLT, where you then have to stick to HTML5 syntax which does not support prefixed element names and only a few predefined attributes (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0). That way you should get consistent results.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand that the output to the browser should be XML. I guess that's what happens when one mixes the lessons from W3Schools to make a web page. In any case this is the magic.

Comment: Somewhat off topic -- Where may I find a good lint type application that would flag this sort of thing? I guess I misunderstood what xmllint and xsltproc do.

Comment: Well if you use xsltproc to do the transformation but want to serve it as text/html to be parsed by the HTML5 parsers of modern browsers then you can run your result document through an HTML5 validator, for instance https://validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.arcor.de%2Fmartin.honnen%2Fxslt%2Ftest2015020802.html gives errors like "Attribute xmlns:svg not allowed here". If you do XSLT directly in the browser then I am not sure there is currently a nice tool, I am not sure whether the browser console of the various developer tools browsers come with gives any helpful warning or error messages.